# get IP adresses of my local network

Tags: python, windows, dhcp, service-discovery

I am working on a GUI program to command power supplies by Ethernet.
I have the DHCP of my computer activated, therefore I guess that the IP adresses of my power supplies are fixed by my computer.
I would like to know the IP addresses of my power supplies, in order to communicate with them through the TCP/IP protocol, using Python.

For the moment, I use a program called LXI discovery tools, and while I run it, the Window command  `arp -a` command gives me the IP adresses of my power supplies.

The problem is that I need to run this LXI program. Is it obligatory? 
Owing to the DCHP, my computer is the one which sets the IP addresses, therefore isn't there a way to get those addresses more easily?
Moreover, is the Python socket library able to help me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem, using statique IP addresses. Therefore I know them and I don't need anymore to "scan" my network.